# Put group of elements below another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to recreate the icicle graph with lots of nodes with HTML / CSS / JS. Example: https://google.com/search?q=icicle+graph

I know that there are libs like `D3` for this, and used some earlier but I wasn't able to customize it for my needs.

---

I try to put elements below other elements like on the picture below:

[image]

The above picture is just a visual representation of what I try to accomplish.

The rows are generated dynamically and I just need to align them properly in the following way:

**Group of child elements should be stacked to the certain parent element.**

I tried the following solution, using `<div>`s:

- Find *left offset* of the parent element
- Stack child elements under the parent element with a found offset
- Preserve elements responsibility

The solution almost worked but elements are stacked with some offset.

Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vash1/zequc29r/8/)

---

**If there are any other simpler solutions for this layout with CSS `grid` or HTML `table` i will be grateful for the hint.**

---

The code looks like the following:

Colors don't matter. It just for visual representation. I've put children under parent and marked them in the same color for better visibility.

```js
function move_childs(child_id, parent_id) {

  const parent = document.getElementById(parent_id)
  const child = document.getElementById(child_id)

  const parent_width_perc = parseInt(parent.style.width)
  const parent_width_px = parent.offsetWidth

  const parent_offset_px = parent.offsetLeft

  // make responsible - calc offset in % 
  // widht % = width px
  // offset % = offset px

  const parent_offset_perc = parent_width_perc * parent_offset_px / parent_width_px

  child.style.position = 'fixed'
  child.style.left = parent_offset_perc + '%'
}

move_childs('blue-child', 'blue-parent')
move_childs('red-child', 'red-parent')
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
}

#gray-parent {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

#blue-parent,
#blue-child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)
}

#red-parent,
#red-child {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="gray-parent" style="width:10%"></div>
<div id="blue-parent" style="width:60%"></div>
<div id="red-parent" style="width:20%"></div>

<br>


<div id="blue-child" style="width: 30%">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>


<div id="red-child" style="width: 10%">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's unclear, picture and jsfiddle don't match, no js either in the fiddle. I do not  understand what are the groups and where children stands. colors ? Could you clarify ? (turning your bits of code into a snippet you can update)

Comment: Colors don't matter. It just for visual representation. I've put children under parent and marked them in the same color for better visibility. JSFiddle has js code in `<script>` tag. If the code is simple and short it is a bit faster to experiment with it when all of your code in one vertical pane. Moved it to JS pane and updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

**** UPDATE

A little explanation of what is going on here:

1. The parent `div` is set to `display:grid` and split into 12 columns. Change this number to whatever you want, I like 12 because it is familiar to me from Bootstrap.
2. Each child element gets a `grid-column` property (See link below).
3. With this CSS property you can "offset" columns and "span" columns.
4. The `span` keyword spans a number of columns.
5. A numeric value to the left of the slash offsets columns.
6. The numeric value to the right of the slash represents the number of columns to span after the offset. A `-1` value denotes a span to the end of the row.

**** ORIGINAL

Here is one way you can easily do this using [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).

```css
.grid-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  background: slategray;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell-1 {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.cell-2 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.cell-3 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.cell-4 {
  grid-column: 4/span 9;
}

.cell-5 {
  grid-column: 4/span 3;
}

.cell-6 {
  grid-column: 7/-1;
}

.cell-7 {
  grid-column: 3/9;
}

.cell-8 {
  grid-column: 9/span 4;
}

.cell-9 {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-box">
  <div class="cell cell-1">1</div>
  <div class="cell cell-2">2</div>
  <div class="cell cell-3">3</div>
  <div class="cell cell-4">4</div>
  <div class="cell cell-5">5</div>
  <div class="cell cell-6">6</div>
  <div class="cell cell-7">7</div>
  <div class="cell cell-8">8</div>
  <div class="cell cell-9">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks extremely helpful. Thank you so much. I will give it a try

Comment: Sounds good, glad to help. If you share a little more about how you are going to use this layout maybe i can help more.

Comment: I am trying to recreate the icicle graph with lots of nodes with HTML / CSS / JS. Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=icicle+graph  I know that there are libs like `d3` for this, and used some earlier but I wasn't able to customize it for my needs.

Comment: Shouldnt be too hard with CSS grid and transform rotate